# Java NullPointerException, please help me understand why

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

**EDIT:** The problem I were having was that I were using the wrong socket. It's now solved.

Hi,

I am working on a little chat client in java which include socket programming. However I've got a little problem starting up my connection because I get a NullPointerException and I can't understand why!

This is the code making the troubles:

```
        try {
            sock = new Socket(host, port);
            Connection DaUberConnection = new Connection(sock);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The variables used for creating the socket is declared at at class level and is fully working as intended (I think). Host and port is set.

```
Socket sock;
String host;
int port;
```

I understand that it has something to do with me throwing in a null in the wrong place somewhere, but I can't really see how this is hanging all together.

Sorry for my bad english or nubieness in java :)
It would be gold if anyone could explain why this is happening!

Full error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at clientpackage.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:24)
at clientpackage.Client$1.actionPerformed(Client.java:91)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you ever set the value for `host`? If not, then `host` would be null and would cause an exception

Comment: What is on line 24 of Connection.java?

Comment: Yes I have set a value for host which is "localhost" right now.

Comment: On line 24:
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

Comment: Be sure you're using the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) as recommended.

Comment: Skip Head: Yes I understand that, but how can I fix it? I can't see how I can create sock in another way :/

Comment: Without seeing actual code that demonstrates the issue ... it's pretty impossible to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Show us the constructor for the Connection class.

Comment: Note: don't mark the question solved by changing the title. Instead accept an existing answer, or write your own answer and accept it if no existing answer is adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you've not built and deployed the same code that is in your question.

- You say that the exception occurs at this line:

  ```
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
  ```

  and that means that `sock` MUST be null.
- But that is called from here:

  ```
  sock = new Socket(host, port);  // 1
  Connection DaUberConnection = new Connection(sock); // 2
  ```

  and that means that `sock` CANNOT be null ... unless something else is going on.

If the code that you are running **really is** as you have reported, the only possible explanation of those symptoms is if some other thread is assigning `null` to `sock` in the tiny window between the two statements (`1` and `2`).  Even assuming some other thread *can* update `sock`, this event will only occur "once in a blue moon".

---

Go back to your development environment, save all files you are editing, clean out all of the ".class" files, a full build, and run your application over again.

---

I think I see your problem ... `s` versus `sock`.

This is a good illustration of why it is BAD PRACTICE for a class to expose its state variables to subclasses.  The `sock` instance variable should be `private` and the subclass should use a getter to access it and should initialize it via constructor chaining.

Get some sleep, then tomorrow start by fixing this design flaw.

Comment: This is Connection.java in its current state: http://pastie.org/private/jec4n2s22c6hm5aj10ts3a

Comment: Hm, forgot that I had extended client in connection making sock availblie in connection. The socket I should use is of course "s" not sock. Sorry I am tired! :D

Answer (score 0):

Separate the line 24.

Use

```
if (sock==null) System.out.println ("Sock is null");
else {
    is = sock.getInputStream(); 
    if (is==null) System.out.println ("inputStream is null");
    else isr = InputStreamReader(is);
}
```

and see which one is null. What is this line for?

```
Connection DaUberConnection = new Connection(sock);
```

Comment: `getInputStream()` can't return null. This serves no purpose. `sock` is null.

Comment: @Brian you're right. Reading the documentation, Socket throws an IOException it if can't create the stream. I just assumed it returned null.